# Changing background-color of checkboxlist BOX

Tags: c#, asp.net, background-color, checkboxlist

I need to know how to style the gray box in a asp.net C# checkboxlist, not the whole item, only the gray box, anyone know how to do that?

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a built in property: BackColor. (hit spacebar after "server" and it should show up.)

Answer (score 0):

If, by "the gray box", you mean the checkbox itself, I am afraid that you cannot do it easily (see [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)). In order to try to replace the checkbox element with your own, you would have to use the CssClass property:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server" CssClass="chkList">

<style type="text/css">
    .chkList input
    {
        // Use CSS to replace the checkbox element
    }
</style>
```